# How to use model.predict for Categorical Cross Entropy?

Tags: python, keras

So, I just trained my model.

Edit(Here's how I got the classes)

```
classes = os.path.join('emnist-letters-mapping.txt')
with open(classes, 'r') as f:
    classes = f.readlines()
    classes = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), classes))
    print(classes)
num_classes = len(classes)
```

Got labels in .txt file.

```
pred = model.predict(train_features)#[0]#np.array(set_one).reshape((-1,48,48,3)))#
print(pred)
result = [(classes[i], float(pred[i]) * 100.0) for i in range(len(pred))]
result.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
for i in range(2):
    (class_name, prob) = result[i]
    print("Top %d ====================" % (i + 1))
    print("Class name: %s" % (class_name))
    print("Probability: %.2f%%" % (prob))
```

Now when I use predictions I get returned with this

```
[[[[0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 1.9776728e-02
    4.9749532e-35 3.3859247e-21 5.2264658e-22 0.0000000e+00
    0.0000000e+00 2.0263837e-21 1.3618594e-32 0.0000000e+00
    4.4031281e-35 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
    6.0703663e-32 0.0000000e+00 6.8396845e-19 0.0000000e+00
    4.3259302e-11 0.0000000e+00 1.1961731e-34 0.0000000e+00
    2.8515963e-19 9.8022330e-01 0.0000000e+00]]]]
```

But when I try it to multiply with my labels files, to which I get an error

```
File "model_predict.py", line 42, in <module>
    result = [(classes[i], float(pred[i]) * 100.0) for i in range(len(pred))]
  File "model_predict.py", line 42, in <listcomp>
    result = [(classes[i], float(pred[i]) * 100.0) for i in range(len(pred))]
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: can you provide `classes`?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `pred` is a numpy array with shape (1, 1, 1, 27)

In order to iterate it and use its item as key for the dict properly, you have to flatten it.

Try to add this line before `result = [(classes[i], float(pred[i]) * 100.0) for i in range(len(pred))]`

```
pred = list(pred.flatten())
```

Because when at the first iteration of your loop, i will be an array with shape (1,1,27) which cannot use for lookup the dict.